# How can I make this button image appear in Firefox 2.0 the same as it does in IE7?

Tags: css, firefox2

I have a CSS file for my anchor links defined below. This works fine for IE7 but when I open 
the page in Firefox the button image is longer.

I Googled to see if Firefox has a background position bug but didn't find anything.

How can I fix this issue?

The CSS file is below:

```
/* button settings */
a.RadForm_CustomSkins, a.RadForm_CustomSkins span
{
    background-image: url('FormDecorator/ButtonSprites.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdInputDisabled:hover
{
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins .rfdInner,
a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdInputDisabled:hover .rfdInner
{
    margin-right: 11px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    background-position: 0 -21px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:11px;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdInputDisabled:hover .rfdOuter
{
    background-position: right 0%;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins:hover
{
    background-position: 0 -42px;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins:hover .rfdInner
{
    background-position: 0 -63px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins:hover .rfdOuter
{
    background-position: right -42px;
}
/* end of button settings */

/* clicked button styles */
a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdClicked
{
    background-image: url('FormDecorator/ButtonSprites.gif');
    background-position: 0 -84px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdClicked span
{
    background-image: url('FormDecorator/ButtonSprites.gif');
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdClicked .rfdInner
{
    background-position: 0 -105px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a.RadForm_CustomSkins.rfdClicked .rfdOuter
{
    background-position: right -84px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* end of clicked button styles */

/* do NOT change these settings, otherwise the skinned buttons will be broken when used within a decoration zone */
a.rfdSkinnedButton.RadForm_CustomSkins
{
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    cursor: default !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    background-position: 0% 0%; 
}
```

and the rendered HTML as button is:

```
    <a id="_rfdSkinnedctl00_signOut" class="rfdSkinnedButton RadForm_CustomSkins" href="javascript:void(0)" style="width: 80px;">
<span class="rfdOuter">
<span class="rfdInner">Çıkış</span>
</span>
</a>
<input id="ctl00_signOut" class="rfdRealButton" type="submit" value="Çıkış" name="ctl00$signOut" _rfddecoratedid="_rfdSkinnedctl00_signOut"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is that the width of the button appears differently in IE and Firefox.  Here are some things you can try:

1. Explicitly set the width of the button.
2. Use max-width to limit the width of the button in Firefox (IE7 doesn't understand this property unless you declare "XHTML 1.0 Strict" in your DTD).
3. Have a look to see if any divs/tables/other elements are affecting the size of your button.
4. Check to see if margin/border/padding properties are having an affect.
5. Start a clean page and build the problem up from scratch to see if you can recreate the issue.  (You have quite a lot going on in your example above, and you perhaps need to distill your thoughts.)